# Share same IP for multiple pods

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

Is it possible to expose pods application of different ports on single IP on different port for example that

```
microservices-cart       LoadBalancer   10.15.251.89    35.195.135.146   80:30721/TCP  
microservices-comments   LoadBalancer   10.15.249.230   35.187.190.124   80:32082/TCP  
microservices-profile    LoadBalancer   10.15.244.188   35.195.255.183   80:31032/TCP
```

would look like

```
microservices-cart       LoadBalancer   10.15.251.89    35.195.135.146   80:30721/TCP  
microservices-comments   LoadBalancer   10.15.249.230   35.195.135.146   81:32082/TCP  
microservices-profile    LoadBalancer   10.15.244.188   35.195.135.146   82:31032/TCP
```

Comment: i don't think kubernetes exposes a way to do this, so this is quite not possible imho.

Comment: Why don't you group them into one pod?

Comment: ccshih this is also one of the solutions. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the same external IP is usually accomplished by using ingress resources.

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

But you'll have to route with paths instead of ports.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to combine [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) and a reverse proxy. NodePort expose pods on different ports on all nodes. The reverse proxy serves as the entrance and redirects traffic to nodes.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another you'll have to consolidate onto the same pod.

You can create a deployment that proxies each of the ports to the appropriate service. There are plenty of ways to create a TCP proxy - via nginx, node via package, there's a Go package maintained by Google; whatever you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're building a microservices app, you need an api gateway. It can have an external IP address and communicate with other pods using internal services. One possible way is using nginx. You can watch a guide about api gateways  [here](https://youtu.be/1vjOv_f9L8I).